# Create constant or tensor without knowing shape upfront in Keras/TF?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am working on a custom method to categorize text documents. Each document has shape (None, 3) where None represents the number of tokens in the document and it's variable. Each batch is then going to have shape (None, None, 3), where the first value represents the batch_size.

In one of my custom layer, I need to create a square matrix of 0s of size equals to the number of tokens for that document. The issue is, when the graph is instantiated, I have no idea what number this is going to be. In fact, this number is likely different for each document.

To make things even more difficult, this operation is done as part of K.map_fn(), which makes it impossible to create new tensors. K.constant would work just great if I knew the number of tokens beforehand (assuming it was also the same for all documents).

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`tf.zeros_like`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/zeros_like).

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, None))
z = tf.zeros_like(x) # zeros the same shape and dtype as x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the shape of the tensor using [`tf.shape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape). You can also split it into individual dimensions like this:

```
batch_size, num_tokens, last_dim = tf.unstack(tf.shape(input_tensor))
```

Then you can use these variables for creating the matrix:

```
tf.zeros([batch_size, num_tokens] dtype=tf.float32)
```